# How to solve SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) while fetching JSON data in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, json, api, express, parsing

I am new in Backend development, Since last few days I am trying to get a response from the api and show it on my html page and i am constantly getting this error while parsing JSON . I am using NodeJS with ExpressJS . Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the error :
undefined:1
{"pagination":{"limit":100,"offset":0,"count":22,"total":22},"data":[{"flight_date":"2022-05-01","flight_status":"landed","departure":{"airport":"Vadodara","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","iata":"BDQ","icao":"VABO","terminal":null,"gate":null,"delay":16,"scheduled":"2022-05-01T11:55:00+00:00","estimated":"2022-05-01T11:55:00+00:00","actual":"2022-05-01T12:10:00+00

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\2kwattz\Desktop\2kaerostack\server.js:31:35)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:390:28)
at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:527:10)
at flow (node:internal/streams/readable:1012:34)
at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:993:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

Here is the code:

```js
app.post("/airportracker", function (req, res) {

    let apiKey = 'somekey';  
    let airportiata = req.body.airportiata;
    let url = `http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=${apiKey}&dep_iata=${airportiata}`;
    http.get(url, function (response) {
        response.on('data', function (data) {

            console.log(data);

            let flightData = JSON.parse(data);
            flightData = flightData.stringify();


            console.log(flightData);
            let flightDate = flightData.data[0].flight_date;

            res.send(`${flightDate}`)


        });
    })


})
```

Here is the form code:

```html
 <form class="airportracker" action="/airportracker" method="POST">

        <label for="airportIata"> Enter Airport IATA </label>
        <input type="text" name="airportiata" id="airportiata">

        <a href="#"> Psst! Don't know your Airport IATA ? Click here ! </a>

        <button class="btn" id="airportTrackerSubmit" type="submit"> Track Flights </button>
    </form>
```

I would be really grateful if anyone provides me a solution. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You assume that the entire response comes with *one* `data` event, but this is not guaranteed, that's why you end up with only a first chunk of JSON (with an "unexpected end").

You must be prepared for several [`data`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/stream.html#event-data) events, followed by a single [`end`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/stream.html#event-end) event:

```js
var data = "";
response.on('data', function(chunk) {
  data += chunk.toString();
})
.on('end', function() {
  console.log(data);
  /* Rest of your code */
});
```

(I don't understand where the `undefined:1` in your error log comes from, however.)

Comment: Hi Heiko ! Thank you so much for your answer , I tried following up with what you just said, I created two response.on , one with data and one with end . But still i am getting this error, undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Here is my new code http.get(url, function (response) {

        console.log(response.statusCode);
        response.on("data", function(data){
            

        })

        response.on("end", function (data) {
            const flightData = JSON.parse(data);
const airlineIcao = flightData.data.airline.icao;
 res.send(`  Airline ICAO : ${airlineIcao}`);

Can you help me with this one? Thank you so much !

Comment: Your code differs from my answer, please look again. For example, there is no `var data` in your code.