# when i click the button the post request is being sent and also console.log is working fine in app.post but the res.send() does not reflect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

when i click the button with class(.hw) the  post request is being sent and also console.log is working fine in app.post but the res.send() does not reflect in the browser.I also tried to end response but that did not make any diffrence.
ALSO this is the first time i am using stack overflow also i am absolute beginner so pls explain in simple terms.

INDEX.js :

```
let obj = {
    message: "hello world"
};

document.querySelector(".hw").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    fetch("/",{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(obj),
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

APP.js

```
const exp = require("express");
const app = exp();


app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
    req.on("close",() => res.end());
});

app.get("/index.js",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.js");
});

app.post("/",(req,res) => {
    req.on('data',data => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data).message);
        res.send(JSON.parse(data).message);
    });
});

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("server started at 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
fetch("/",{
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(obj),
        }).then(data => {
            return data.json();
        })
        .then(resData=>{console.log(resData)})
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And in the backend

```
app.post("/",(req,res) => {
    const data=req.body;
    console.log(data);
    res.send("request success") //res.json(data) for sending data back to UI
});
```

Comment: I tried this and got the following error in the console: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0"  also still the browser does not reflect the changes.

Comment: Somewhere some typo is happening. Please check and also make the change as suggested in the other answer. Before defining routes do
app.use(express.json())

Comment: I tried everything but it seems there is some problem with the response stream as i commented everything and simply tried res.send("hello world"); and still it failed show up on the browser. I also put req.on('close',()=>res.end()); but that did not help either.

Comment: Try the updated answer. Don't forget to put the app.use(express.json()) before all the route declarations

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72076993/16462950

As an alternative to parsing the JSON yourself, you can write

```js
app.post("/", express.json(), (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body.message);
  res.send(req.body.message);
});
```